# Move Animation in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, animation

I'm trying move animation within screen, here's the code

```
Animation<TextureRegion> animation_run = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, 
    Gdx.files.internal("run.gif").read());
    float elapsedTime += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) * 2;
    float playablePosition = (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) / 2 - 200;
    float currentPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; currentPosition <= playablePosition; i++) {
    currentPosition += i;
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(animation_run.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), currentPosition, 0, 200, 300);
batch.end();
}
```

but I got not exactly what I want[image]

Does anybody know how fix my code to make movement from left edge to the center properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in this code

```
for (int i = 0; currentPosition <= playablePosition; i++) {
    currentPosition += i;
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(animation_run.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), currentPosition, 0, 200, 300);
    batch.end();
}
```

Instead of looping through adding the animation we want to just draw the animation once in the batch and draw it in different position each frame. Below I change the position of the animation by incrementing position

```
Animation<TextureRegion> animation_run = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, 
Gdx.files.internal("run.gif").read());
float elapsedTime += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()) * 2;
float playablePosition = (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) / 2 - 200;
// float currentPosition = 0; // <-- this needs set outside ouside of the render method.
currentPosition += 1;
batch.begin();
batch.draw(animation_run.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime), currentPosition, 0, 200, 300);
batch.end();
```